# Spring Kafka and number of topic consumers

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, messaging, spring-kafka

In my Spring Boot/Kafka project I have the following consumer config:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(kafkaProperties));
        factory.setConcurrency(10);    
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Post> postConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Post.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> postKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(postConsumerFactory(kafkaProperties));

        return factory;
    }

}
```

This is my `PostConsumer`:

```
@Component
public class PostConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.post.send}", containerFactory = "postKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void sendPost(ConsumerRecord<String, Post> consumerRecord) {

        postService.sendPost(consumerRecord.value());

    }

}
```

and the application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${kafka.host}:${kafka.port}
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=groupname
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
kafka.topic.post.send=post.send
kafka.topic.post.sent=post.sent
kafka.topic.post.error=post.error
```

As you may see, I have added **factory.setConcurrency(10);** but it doesn't work. All of the `PostConsumer.sendPost` execute in the same Thread with name `org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-8-C-1`

I'd like to be able to control the number of concurrent `PostConsumer.sendPost` listeners in order to work in parallel. Please show me how it can be achieved with Spring Boot and Spring Kafka.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is here with consistency we are chasing in Spring Kafka using Apache Kafka Consumer. Such a concurrency is distributed between *partitions* in the topics provided. If you have only one topic and one partition in it, then there is indeed not going to be any concurrency. The point is to consume all the records from one partition in the same thread.

There is some info on the matter in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_concurrentmessagelistenercontainer

> If, say, 6 TopicPartition s are provided and the concurrency is 3; each container will get 2 partitions. For 5 TopicPartition s, 2 containers will get 2 partitions and the third will get 1. If the concurrency is greater than the number of TopicPartitions, the concurrency will be adjusted down such that each container will get one partition.

And also JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The maximum number of concurrent {@link KafkaMessageListenerContainer}s running.
 * Messages from within the same partition will be processed sequentially.
 * @param concurrency the concurrency.
 */
public void setConcurrency(int concurrency) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one instance of Kafka inside of the Docker container. How to check the partition number and how to manage it?

Comment: You can use the command line tool `kafka-topics.sh` to query and adjust the number of partitions on your topic(s). You can also add a `NewTopic` `@Bean` and boot's auto configured `KafkaAdmin` will adjust the partitions up if the `NewTopic` has a larger number than the current.

Comment: Is there any difference between running 5 instances of the same app with concurrency mentioned at 1. Vs running one instance of the app with its concurrency set to 5. If I do have 5 partitions on kafka topic then isn't the first setup better at achieving parallelism. Because the second setup will give me more threads that will just start contending for CPU time. I am assuming that my CPU has single core for this discussion.

Comment: Right, having 5 instances is better because they don’t share the CPU

Answer (score 2):

To create & manage partitioned topic,

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_URL);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topicToTarget() {
    return new NewTopic(Constant.Topic.PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC_NAME, <no. of partitions>, (short) <replication factor>);
}
```

To send message into different partitions, use Partitioner interface

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_URL);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, <your custom Partitioner implementation>);

    return props;
}
```

To consume message from multiple partitions using a single consumer (each message from different partitions will spawn new thread and consumer method will be called in parallel)

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions = {
        @TopicPartition(
                topic = Constant.Topic.PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC_NAME,
                partitions = "#{kafkaGateway.createPartitionArray()}"
        )
}, groupId = "group.processor")
public void consumeWriteRequest(@Payload String data) {
  //your code
}
```

Here the consumers (if multiple instances started) belongs to same group, hence one of them will be invoked for each message.